# How to effectively save & restore data from the last three months and delete the old data?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL. I need to delete all transaction data from database (except the last three month transaction data) then restore the data to new database with created/updated timestamp updated to now timestamp. Also the data more from last three months must be recaped into one data (example all invoice from party A must be grouped into one invoice with party A). Other rules is if the data is still foreign keys referenced for the last three month data.The data must not be deleted and only change the created/updated timestamp to now timestamp.

I am not good in SQL query so for now I am using this strategy:

1. First create the recap data (save in other temporary table) before delete (All data).
2. Then delete all data except the last three months.
3. Next create the recap data after delete.
4. Create the recap data from (All data - After delete data) so i get the recap data with nominal exactly same with data before the last three month.
5. Then insert the recap data to table. So the old data is clean + have recap data in the database.

So my strategy is only using same database and not create new database because process importing data using the program is very slow (because have 900++ tables).

But the client doesn't want use this strategy because he want the data is created in new database and tell me to using other way. So the question is: What is the real and correct procedure to clean database from some dates (filter with date) and recap the old data?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is no way to find out when a row was added to a table unless you track it with a timestamp column.

That's the first change you'll have to make – add a timestamp column to all relevant columns that tracks when the row was created (or updated, depending on the requirement).

Then you have two choices:

- [Partition](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html) the tables by the timestamp column so that you have (for example) one partition per month.
  **Advantage:** it is easy to get rid of old data: just drop the partition.
  **Disadvantage:** Partitioning is tricky in PostgreSQL. It will become somewhat [easier to handle in PostgreSQL v10](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/ddl-partitioned-tables.html), but the underlying problems remain.
- Use mass `DELETE`s to get rid of old rows. That's easy to implement, but mass deletes really hurt (table and index bloat which might necessitate `VACUUM (FULL)` or `REINDEX` which impair availability).

Comment: i already have created and last updated timestamp column in all tables.